# Displaying in a view based on a checkbox in a form

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm having some issues getting the value of a checkbox from a form. I'm probably doing something wrong, but I can't figure it out for the life of me.

The code in my view looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DisplayEmpPhotos", "Home", null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "GetEmpNumbers" }))
{


<div id = "empForm">
    <br/>
    Event Name:<input type ="text" name="EventName"/>
    <br/>
    Event Dates:<input type ="text" name="EventDates"/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Enter Employee IDs:
    <br/>
    Consultant: <input type="checkbox" name="consultant" value="include" checked="checked" />
    <br/>
}
```

There are several textbox inputs below that checkbox, but they work fine.

The code in my controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult DisplayEmpPhotos(string EventName, string EventDates, string consultant)
{
    ViewData["EventName"] = EventName;
    ViewData["EventDates"] = EventDates;
    if(consultant == "include")
    {
        ViewData["Image"] = "<img src ='imgsrc' alt='First&nbsp;Last' class='nopad'/>";
        ViewData["Name"] = "First&nbsp;Last";
        ViewData["Deparment"] = "C";
        ViewData["Title"] = "Consultant";
    }
```

The view has this in it:

```
<td class="smalltext">
        @ViewData["Image"]
        <p>
        @ViewData["Name"]
        </p>
        @ViewData["Department"]
        <br/>
        @ViewData["Title"]
</td>
```

My thought was that if the box is checked, the value of it is passed and I should be able to assign Viewdata to that information and display it in the view. I know hardcoding values like this is bad practice, but for what I'm doing it's acceptable. Any help with what I'm doing wrong is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the variable in your Controller method named "checkbox" when it should be "consultant", and you really should use the Html `CheckBox` helper.

So in the View:

```
Consultant: @Html.Checkbox("consultant", true)
```

And in the Controller, change the value to be a boolean:

```
public ActionResult DisplayEmpPhotos(string EventName, string EventDates, bool consultant)
{
   ViewData["EventName"] = EventName;
   ViewData["EventDates"] = EventDates;

   if(consultant)
   {
       ViewData["Image"] = "<img src ='imgsrc' alt='First&nbsp;Last' class='nopad'/>";
       ViewData["Name"] = "First&nbsp;Last";
       ViewData["Deparment"] = "C";
       ViewData["Title"] = "Consultant";
   }
}
```

Let me know if this doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. The data still is not showing up in my view however. I'll edit the question with that code as well.

Answer (score 0):

If in your *ActionResult* you change from `string checkbox` to `string consultant`?

Some times MVC does that to me, and when I change the names of the inputs to exactly how I declared them in my actionResult, they work.